# How can I combine parameter I pass with other letters?

Tags: bash, shell

How can I combine a variable with another character?

Below is the var that I pass in shell

```
export value_max=6
```

Lets say I wanted to call it from sql as below

```
@db_oracle/abc.sql  max_size 6g
```

how can I add the letter **g**?

```
@db_oracle/abc.sql  max_size $value_max
```

Comment: When you say “call it from SQL”, what exactly does that mean? Is the `.sql` file marked as executable?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried simply appending the variable with the character?

`@db_oracle/abc.sql max_size $value_max'g'`

If it feels cleaner to you, you could create another variable, assigning the appended variable as the value:

`export value_max_with_unit=$value_max'g'`
`@db_oracle/abc.sql max_size $value_max_with_unit`

Answer (score 0):

Simply adding a letter to the end of the variable doesn't work, as bash would look for a variable called `$value_maxg`.  But you can wrap the name of the variable in curly braces to make it unambiguous, like this:

```
@db_oracle/abc.sql  max_size ${value_max}g
```

The curly braces become manditory if you want to use any of bash's more advanced variable expansion rules for things like trimming prefixes or suffixes from a variable or extracting substrings.